# Redux reducer does not change next state store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

here is my little chat app in redux-react
and I have issue with reducer which is not changing next state store

https://github.com/arammkr/chat-redux/blob/master/src/reducers/user.js#L23

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rnqx4jnaho0lbj/Screenshot%202016-05-30%2000.25.17.png?dl=0

this is console log, where you can see that action has user array, but next state users array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to switch on `action.type`, not `action`.

Comment: Cool.  In that case, might as well accept the answer :)